# Temporarily deactivate button until a certain service function resolves using a custom directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service

I would like to disable a certain group of buttons that are available(I am using ngClick on those buttons) only for active users, and enable them again after the request that verifies that the account is indeed active resolves.

My current implementation is as follows:

```
directive('activeCompanyButton', function(authService, companyService) {
    var defualtFunction = function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    };
    function bind(elem){
      elem.addClass('disabled');
      elem.bind('click', defualtFunction);
    }
    function unbind(elem){
     elem.removeClass('disabled');
     elem.unbind('click', defualtFunction);
    }
    return{
      // scope: false,
      link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
        bind(elem);
      },
      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs, authService, companyService){
        function checkCompanyStatus(val){
          var company = val;
           var r = company && company.status == 'active';  
           return r;
        }
        $scope.$watch(function(){return companyService.getCompanyData(authService.getCompanyId())}, function(val){
          console.log(val);
          if(checkCompanyStatus(val)){
            unbind($element);
            $element.bind('click', $scope.$eval($attrs.ngClick));
          }
          else{
            bind($element);
          }
        });
      }
    }
});
```

None of that is working, not even the $scope.$eval()(should i strip the '()' from the function name and leave the function to give the function reference rather than a function call?).

should I be using an isolate scope, I am not currently doing that because to the best of my understanding that would create multiple instances of dirty-checking(watchers) instead of just one.

Comment: Has this ever worked? That's a lot of code for "none of it is working"

Comment: I wouldn't bind and unbind events, just toggle the `disabled` attribute of the element.

Comment: ah, how do I do that within a directive?

Comment: @tymeJV What I meant was that I haven't managed to unbind the event, and then bind it back again successfully so far.

Comment: You're referencing `elem` before the `link:` function, isn't that throwing an error?

Comment: Example on using an element's disabled attribute: http://jsfiddle.net/5hXmQ/1/

Comment: You can use `ng-disabled` on the button based on a flag (model) signifying whether the use is active or not. Obviously, the flag will be driven by the controller/service whichever determines that the user is active now.

Comment: @m.e.conroy Looks like we were thinking alike. You were acting on it as well. ;)

Comment: @dmahapatro totally, I saw all those `bind` and `unbind`s and thought this really is a job for the `ng-disabled` directive and an simple true/false flag.  Would cut out alot of code.

Comment: Here's an example that uses a "faked" service, such that when the service is done making its call the button will be available to use: http://jsfiddle.net/96Xvs/1/

Comment: Hi guys, I am well aware of the ngDisabled directive.
The point was to implement a custom directive to do this is a generic way.

Comment: @tymeJV the elem you are referring to is a parameter in a function declaration, thus it is not raising an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this structure in your code:

```
<active-company-button>
    <button style="custom" other="blah" />
</active-company-button>
```

One way to do this is add a templateUrl property to your directive to include a template that wraps a standard button & adds ng-disabled. You can then take advantage of ng-disabled's behavior for every button without having to add it to each button. Disadvantage is you have to put styling & other properties on the "outer" directive instead of on the button itself.

So, the above code would become this:

```
<active-company-button style="custom" other="blah" />
```